# Replace every line with "&"

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was looking for a Batch file, that could replace every line with a "&".

MYFILE1.bat

```
@echo off
echo Hello!
pause
exit
```

After converting -> MYFILE2.bat

```
@echo off & echo Hello! & pause & exit
```

I was trying this, but it isnt working:

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search= "
set "replace=&"

set "textFile=MYFILE1.bat"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

Is there any way, to make .BAT do this?
Thanks!

Comment: To begin with, your question text does not match your expected end result. You seemingly want to replace a `carriage return`/`linefeed` pair with `space`/`ampersand`/`space`, not `ampersand`. However by doing that, instead of `echo`ing `Hello!`, you're now `echo`ing ```Hello! ```, _(note the additional space character)_, which may not necessarily have been the intention.

Comment: Please also note, irrespective of the additional spaces you're introducing, many batch files, converted in this way, will no longer work as intended, and may completely fail. There is no benefit in a batch file having multiple commands in sequence on the same line, and apart from that, there is also a potential command line length restriction. Don't do it, and if you do decide to, most certainly do not try to perform the modification directly to the same file, you'll have nothing to go back to if problems occur, and would have to try to manually adjust all problem ones later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little trickery with the `SET /P` command and `NUL` redirection.  This will have a trailing `&` at the end of the final script but that will not cause any errors.

```
@echo off
set "textFile=MYFILE1.bat"

for /f "delims=" %%G in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    >>"%textFile%" SET /P ".=%%G&"<nul
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

```
C:>powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path '.\MYFILE1.bat') -join ' & '"
```

The result.

```
 8:21:55.46  C:\src\t
C:>powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path '.\MYFILE1.bat') -join ' & '"
@echo off & echo Hello! & pause & exit
```

It is even easier if you can use the PowerShell console or make a .ps1 script file.

```
(Get-Content -Path '.\MYFILE1.bat') -join ' & '
```